# Given $a_{1} = \frac{1}{2},\;\;a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n} +3}{4},\;\;n ≥ 1$, find $L = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$a_{1} = \frac{1}{2},\;\;a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n} +3}{4},\;\;n ≥ 1.$$
Need help to find L: $L = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}$.

I have already found out that it is upper bounded by 1 and that it is ultimately increasing. If someone also can answer or show that it is converges, would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: If a sequence is monotonic and bounded it must converge.  Show that 1 is the least upper bound, and you are done.

Comment: This question was reposted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407007/given-a-1-frac12-a-n1-fraca-n-34-n-%e2%89%a5-1-i-need-t), after the closure of this question.

Answer (score 3):

$(a_n)$ converges because it is increasing and bounded. $(a_{n+1})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, so it has the same limit $L$ as $(a_n)$. But $a_{n+1} = (a_n + 3)/4$, so its limit is also $(L + 3)/4$. Therefore $L = (L + 3)/4$, which gives $L = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

As Doug M pointed out in the comment, it suffices to show that $1$ is the least upper bound for this sequence.

---

An alternative elementary approach is as follows: Observe that $$a_{n+1}-1=\frac{a_n+3}{4}-1=\frac{a_n-1}{4},$$ so $$a_n-1=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}(a_1-1)=\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)=-\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^{n-1}}.$$ Therefore, $$a_n=1-\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^{n-1}}\to 1$$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

To find such $-1$, we may let $c$ be a constant to be determined and write $$a_{n+1}+c=\frac{a_n+3}{4}+c=\frac{1}{4}(a_n+3+4c).$$ To make it look like a geometric sequence, we can let $$c=3+4c,$$ which gives $c=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I will prove the two facts you had already proven for the reader, and then the fact that the limit is $1$ follows.

Observe that $a_1 = \frac{1}{2} < 1$, and by induction assume $a_n \le 1$. Then,
$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \le \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} = 1$.

In addition, $a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{3}{4} \cdot a_n \ge 0$, since $a_n \le 1$, as above.

Now, as others have pointed out $-$ a bounded, monotonically increasing sequence converges.

Let $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$.

Observe that $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + 3}{4} \iff 4 a_{n+1} - a_n = 3$, for all $n \ge 1$. So that,

$$
3 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\Big(4 a_{n+1} - a_n \Big) = 4L - L = 3L \iff L = 1
$$